# Enable CentOS server to make FTP connections to other windows based server via php

Tags: centos, php, ftp

When I am running this code from my local wamp, it works fine and prints the result.

```
//connection to a ftp server across proxy
putenv('TMPDIR=/tmp/');
$ftp_server = "SERVER IP"; 
$ftp_user_name = "XXXXXX"; 
$ftp_user_pass = "XXXXXX";

$destination_path = "/sanketik/";
$remote_file = $destination_path.$file;

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// enabling passive mode
ftp_pasv( $conn_id, true );

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "/sanketik");

// output $contents
var_dump($contents);
```

Output:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '/sanketik/bittu' (length=15)
  1 => string '/sanketik/mysql.png' (length=19)
  2 => string '/sanketik/shakun' (length=16)
  3 => string '/sanketik/shakun.txt' (length=20)
  4 => string '/sanketik/TTTTT.txt' (length=19)
```

But when I am running same code from my CentOS-based server it gives `NULL`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the audit logs?  I suspect SELinux is preventing your web server from opening up outbound connections to an FTP server.  You might need to set the `httpd_can_network_connect` boolean.  Check the audit logs by running (as root, or through sudo): `ausearch -m avc -ts recent` after attempting to load the web page.  You can set the SELinux boolean with `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`.  Read more about SELinux booleans [here](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans).